# How to run Load Testing in visual studio using Cloud servers or VM?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I created a Web Performance and Load Testing project. I added recording using my website to check the web performance and after that I tried Load Test.
What I want is to how to run load testing from visual studio using any cloud servers or virtual machines?

Why I need that is, if I want to do Load Testing with ex. 1 millions user, my machine can't handle that, and using any Cloud service or VM might be helpful.

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online). It allows you to simulate large amounts of traffic using the Microsoft Cloud.

Please find some helpful articles below with instructions on how to set this up.

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/test/load-test-your-app-vs
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/load-testing.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818498.aspx